# How to avoid hidden QWidget height included in QStackedLayout?

Tags: qt, qt5

I have this scenario with which I have been struggling for few hours:

I have a main widget, whose layout is set to `main_layout`, before which 3 layouts are added to the `main_layout`:

1. A QVBoxLayout (header_app_layout)
2. A second QVBoxLayout (header_loader_layout)
3. A QStackBoxLayout (content_layout)

The QStackBoxLayout (content_layout)  has 2 child widgets added to it, of which only 1 is shown:

1. m_content1_widget (shown widget)
2. m_content2_widget

My problem is that, `content_layout` is taking into consideration the heights of the hidden child widgets in the widget: `m_content1_widget`, because of which the `main_widget` height is overflowing.
If I change `content_layout` from `QStackedLayout` to `QVBoxLayout` type, it all starts working fine.
So it seems to me that, `QStackedLayout` is respecting the height of the hidden widgets, which I don't want it to. Any ideas to overcome this ?
Here is the code:

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    main_widget w;
    w.setFixedSize(400, 400);
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

**main_widget.h**

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QStackedLayout>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>

class main_widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    main_widget();
};
```

**main_widget.cpp**

```
#include "main_widget.h"

main_widget::main_widget()
    : QWidget(nullptr)
{
    QVBoxLayout *header_app_layout = new QVBoxLayout();
    QLabel *header_app_label = new QLabel();
    header_app_label->setText(tr("Header"));
    header_app_layout->addWidget(header_app_label);

    QVBoxLayout* header_loader_layout = new QVBoxLayout();
    QLabel* header_loader_label = new QLabel();
    header_loader_label->setText(tr("Header Loader"));
    header_loader_layout->addWidget(header_loader_label);

    QWidget *m_content1_widget = new QWidget();
    QVBoxLayout* content1_layout = new QVBoxLayout(m_content1_widget);
    QPushButton* content1_button1 = new QPushButton(tr("content1_button1"));
    content1_layout->addWidget(content1_button1);
    QPushButton* content1_button2 = new QPushButton(tr("content1_button2"));
    content1_layout->addWidget(content1_button2);
    QPushButton* content1_button3 = new QPushButton(tr("content1_button3"));
    content1_layout->addWidget(content1_button3);
    content1_button2->hide(); //Hidden for now. But it's height is being included
    content1_button3->hide();

    QWidget* m_content2_widget = new QWidget();
    QVBoxLayout* content2_layout = new QVBoxLayout(m_content2_widget);
    QPushButton* content2_button1 = new QPushButton(tr("content2_button1"));
    content2_layout->addWidget(content2_button1);
    QPushButton* content2_button2 = new QPushButton(tr("content2_button2"));
    content2_layout->addWidget(content2_button2);
    QPushButton* content2_button3 = new QPushButton(tr("content2_button3"));
    content2_layout->addWidget(content2_button3);
    content2_button2->hide();
    content2_button3->hide();


    QStackedLayout* content_layout = new QStackedLayout(); //Doesn't work
    //QVBoxLayout *content_layout = new QVBoxLayout(); //Works, but I need it to be of type `QStackedLayout` to show the 2 child widgets conditionally
    content_layout->addWidget(m_content1_widget);
    content_layout->addWidget(m_content2_widget);
    content_layout->setStackingMode(QStackedLayout::StackingMode::StackOne);
    content_layout->setCurrentIndex(0);

    QVBoxLayout* main_layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    main_layout->addLayout(header_app_layout); //Adding a QVBoxLayout
    main_layout->addLayout(header_loader_layout); //Adding another QVBoxLayout
    main_layout->addSpacing(32);
    main_layout->addLayout(content_layout); //Adding the QStackedLayout

    this->setLayout(main_layout);
}
```

Comment: Does this happen if you use [`QStackedWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html)?

Comment: Yes it happens even with QStackedWidget

Comment: Hmm... I am out of ideas.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know C++ (I only use PyQt) so I cannot give you a complete answer with example code (but if you want I can add an answer with PyQt if you know how to read it and port it to C++). Anyway, yes, all QStackedLayout based widgets always use the sizeHint of their "pages", so the best solution would be to subclass QStackedLayout (about this, be more precise with names, there is no "QStackBoxLayout") and reimplement `sizeHint()` so that it only returns the hint for the current visible widget only (but remember to call `updateGeometry()` when the index changes).

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I have updated the code and fixed the typo (QStackBoxLayout)

Comment: Try using `QGridLayout` (size 1x1), as it supports overlapping widgets. Then just show/hide the widgets in it appropriately. Not sure if this will work, so if anybody tests this and wants to write an answer, go for it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by calling `adjustSize` on `m_content2_widget`, which removed the space occupied by the hidden controls inside `m_content2_widget`.

```
m_content2_widget->adjustSize();
```